# Move button up without affecting css of above tr elements in a table

Tags: html, css, email-templates

I am trying to create an email template so I doing the thing in table only and inline CSS. Problem I am facing with the styling is that I am not able to move the button 40px down the text `You are a .... some task.` without affecting the above 2 `<tr>`s. I applied `height` to `tr` via inline css but somehow it is not taking the height. I also tried setting margin, padding to the last tr, td but no luck.

Let me know how could I achieve this without affecting the heights of above 2 tr, tds or a better way to handle this.

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/qd00shr3/

Code -

```
<body style="background: #2D2D2D; font-family: arial;">
    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="background: green;height: 320px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/008000/fff.png" style="width:100px;height:100px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <h2 style="margin-top: -55px;color: #ffffff;padding: 0 68px 0 60px;font-weight: normal;font-size: 32px;">You are a good developer waiting for some task.</h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 100px;">
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <button style="background: #ff744f; border:none; width: 210px; height: 45px; text-align:center;color: #ffffff;border-radius: 5px;">Check Task</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="background: #ffffff;height: 134px;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p style="font-size: 11px;color: #16325c; text-align: justify;padding: 0 30px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. anim id est laborum.
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: You want to move the button up or down? I'm confused

Comment: @FlorinPop Want to move the button up, clearly mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand correct... This will move your button up:

```
position:relative;top:-40px;
```